# $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \cos \theta + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \sin \theta = \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} (z_0 + r e^{i\theta})$?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $u$ be a function of two variable and all its partial derivative exists and fix $z_0 \in \mathbb C $ and $r>0.$

> My vague question: How to show: $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \cos \theta + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \sin \theta = \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} (z_0 + r e^{i\theta})$ and how to make this rigorous.

My attempt: If we put, $z_{0}=x_{0}+iy_0$, then $z_0 + r e^{i\theta}= (x_{0}+ r \cos \theta) +i(y_{0}+ r \sin \theta)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : it is just the chain rule

$${\partial{u}\over\partial{r}}={\partial{u}\over\partial{x}}{\partial{x}\over\partial{r}}+{\partial{u}\over\partial{y}}{\partial{y}\over\partial{r}}$$

Where $z=z_0+re^{i\theta}$ and $u$ is a function of $z$

Then use $x=x_0+r\cos{\theta}$ and $y=y_0+r\sin{\theta}$